# Django wsgi and mod_pagespeed not working

Tags: apache-2.2, django, wsgi, mod-pagespeed

I installed mod_pagespeed on my server and it's working as far as the page header is concerned:

```
X-Mod-Pagespeed:1.7.30.5-3847
```

The problem is that it's doing nothing else. No whitespace or comment removal or anything that would be obvious. How on earth do I get it setup on my server? What do I need to add to get it to work and what files should I edit? If I can get it doing something then I can probably figure out the rest!

Site config file from sites-enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@site.com
ServerName site.com
#ServerAlias www.site.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/html/
ErrorLog /var/www/site.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/site.com/logs/access.log combined

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/site.com/django/site.com/django.wsgi

Alias /static/ /var/www/site.com/html/static/

<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>

Alias /media/ /var/www/django/contrib/admin/media/

</VirtualHost>
```

WSGI File:

```
import os, sys

sys.stdout = sys.stderr

sys.path.append('/var/www/site.com/django')
sys.path.append('/var/www/site.com/django/sitename')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'sitename.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The pagespeed is using the defaults from when I installed it. Running apache 2.2 on Ubuntu if that helps. Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks